# Update method returns weird data, not updated data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have a problem with update method which returns this object when I run my endpoint

> { n: 1, nModified: 1, ok: 1 }

This is the code which I tried, and I tried with **{ new: true }** but that doesnt help, i want to get updated data back.

```
router.put('/:username/experience/edit/:id', function(req, res) {
    const { title, company, location, from, to, workingNow, description } = req.body;

    User
    .update({'experience._id': req.params.id},
        {'$set': {
            'experience.$.title': title,
            'experience.$.company': company,
            'experience.$.location': location,
            'experience.$.from': from,
            'experience.$.to': to,
            'experience.$.workingNow': workingNow,
            'experience.$.description': description,
        }},
        function(err, model) {
            console.log(model);
            if(err){
                return res.send(err);
            }
            return res.json(model);
        });
})
```

Comment: This is how `update` method works. You have to run `User.find({'experience._id': req.params.id})` again to get updated document

Comment: Try with `findOneAndUpdate` instead of `find` it will return document object for you

Answer (score 1):

If you are on MongoDB 3.0 or newer, you need to use the [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/#db-collection-findoneandupdate)  and use `projection` option to specify the subset of fields to return. You also need to set `returnNewDocument` to `true`.  Of course you need to use the [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) projection operator here because you cannot use a positional projection and return the new document.

As someone pointed out:

> You should be using [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/#db-collection-findoneandupdate) because [`.findAndModify()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/) is highlighed as deprecated in every official language driver. The other thing is that the syntax and options are pretty consistent across drivers for `.findOneAndUpdate()`. With `.findAndModify()`, most drivers don't use the same single object with "query/update/fields" keys. So it's a bit less confusing when someone applies to another language to be consistent. Standardized API changes for `.findOneAndUpdate()` actually correspond to server release 3.x rather than 3.2.x. The full distinction being that the shell methods actually lagged behind the other drivers ( for once ! ) in implementing the method. So most drivers actually had a major release bump corresponding with the 3.x release with such changes.

```js
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate( 
    { 
        "_id": ObjectId("56d6a7292c06e85687f44541"), 
         "rankings._id" : ObjectId("46d6a7292c06e85687f55543") 
    },  
    { $inc : { "rankings.$.score" : 1 } },  
    { 
        "projection": { 
            "rankings": { 
                "$elemMatch": { "_id" : ObjectId("46d6a7292c06e85687f55543") } 
            }
        }, 
        "returnNewDocument": true 
    }
)
```

From MongoDB 3.0 onwards, you  need to use [`findAndModify`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/) and the `fields` options also you need to set `new` to `true` in other to return the new value.

```js
db.collection.findAndModify({   
    query: { 
        "_id": ObjectId("56d6a7292c06e85687f44541"), 
        "rankings._id" : ObjectId("46d6a7292c06e85687f55543") 
    },     
    update: { $inc : { "rankings.$.score" : 1 } },       
    new: true,  
    fields: { 
        "rankings": { 
            "$elemMatch": { "_id" : ObjectId("46d6a7292c06e85687f55543") }
        }  
    }
})
```

Both queries yield:

```js
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56d6a7292c06e85687f44541"),
        "rankings" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("46d6a7292c06e85687f55543"),
                        "name" : "Ranking 2",
                        "score" : 11
                }
        ]
}
```